# How do you get the names of models that have MyObject has_many of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to, model-associations

Using Ruby (1.8.7) and Rails (2.3.8)

doing `myObject.attributes` gives you a hash of attribute to value.

lets say I have the scenario:

```
class MyObject
    has_many :other_objects

class OtherObject
    belongs_to :my_object
```

There should be a way to get the names of the associations tied to an object, right?

Even if there isn't be default, I'd be interested in help with a .associations method, similar to the .attributes -- except, return an array instead of a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[reflect_on_all_associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations) should do it.

Example:

```
MyObject.reflect_on_all_associations.map{|a| a.name.to_s} #=> ["other_objects"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass.reflections
```

Gives you all the associations and aggregations that an activerecord has, and gives you all the information you might need about them (class of the associated objects, foreign key etc.)